# Apache camel can not throw exception for ftp connection error

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

This is my route:

```
        onException(Exception.class)
                .process(reconciliationExceptionProcessor)
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, DOCUMENT_RECONCILIATION_ROUTE, "reconciliationExceptionProcessor")
                .handled(true)
//                .maximumRedeliveries(3).redeliveryDelay(0)
                .to(SEND_MAIL_FOR_FAILED)
                .end();


  from(GET_FILE_FROM_SFTP)
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, DOCUMENT_RECONCILIATION_ROUTE, "Getting the file from SFTP")
                .pollEnrich()
                .simple("${exchangeProperty.sftpExpression}")
                .to(SAVE_RECEIVED_IDS)
                .end();

  from(SAVE_RECEIVED_IDS)
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, DOCUMENT_RECONCILIATION_ROUTE, "Saving the received IDs")
                .process(saveReceivedsProcessor)
```

I tried that expression:

```
t&autoCreate=false&strictHostKeyChecking=no&preferredAuthentications=publickey,password&throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true&bridgeErrorHandler=true
```

But still can not go to exception when SFTP connection is not possible.

At test machine, it hangs. But on my computer, it goes to next route, so i see that log:

```
"Saving the received IDs"
```

But inside, because file is null, it throws null pointer exception for file. But i want it throw to exception about it cant connect to ftp.

I am using that version:

2.18.1

Should i give timeout?

```
timeout
Timeout in millis when polling from the external service. The timeout has influence about the poll enrich behavior. It basically operations in three different modes: negative value - Waits until a message is available and then returns it. Warning that this
 method could block indefinitely if no messages are available. 0 - Attempts to receive a message exchange immediately without waiting and returning null if a message exchange is not available yet. positive value - Attempts to receive a message exchange, waiting
 up to the given timeout to expire if a message is not yet available. Returns null if timed out The default value is -1 and therefore the method could block indefinitely, and therefore its recommended to use a timeout value
```